# How can I check value of CleverTap object?

Tags: javascript, plugins, console, clevertap

Is there a plugin or kind of extension through which I can check what values I am passing in CleverTap object? Apart from accessing the data from CleverTap dashboard, how can I view it on my website?

For e.g., when I include the below code in my JS file,

```
clevertap.profile.push({
 "Site": {
   "Name": "Jack Montana", // User's name
   "Age": 28
 }
});
```

And after refreshing the webpage, when I check the value of cleverTap on my console, I get an empty object,

```
{event: Array(0), profile: Array(0), account: Array(1), onUserLogin: Array(0), notifications: Array(0), …}
```

Why I am not able to see the data which I pushed to profile array? How can I view it apart from cleverTap dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

The CleverTap object is a container to hold the key/values temporarily until they're pushed out to the server endpoint. Once you "push" key/values to the CleverTap object, they go away to the server, and can't be retrieved.

If you want to access user profile data in the webpage itself, you can do so following the steps here - https://support.clevertap.com/docs/personalizing-your-app.html, or use the server side API to access your stored event or profile data - https://support.clevertap.com/docs/api/getting-started.html.